# How to avoid reprocessing of images by ckfinder?

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

I'm running an installation of fork-cms which includes ckfinder which is part of the ckeditor. When I upload images they often come back with much larger filesizes as the uploaded ones which indicates any reprocessing done to them and not checked the resulting filesize!

Example: photo optimized end created by photoshop 1280x960 @ 50% quality -> approx 400k uploaded to the server comes back same dimensions but over 800k in size. When trying to reproduce the quality settings in PS results in approx. 80 to 85% quality.

I turned of imageprocessing for images of larger dimensions which are were set to 1600x1200 by setting them to 0x0.

Comment: Could you provide some links to the modules for fork-cms that includes CKEditor/CKFinder? Or can you tell which versions of CKEditor/CKFinder this CMS is using?

Comment: it is an standard fork 5.2.3 installation, but i think now ckfinder isn't really used for uploads any more despite the settings for ckfinder which i turned off. Ithink the ckfinder version is 4.3.1 or 4.3.2

Comment: On further inspection and talk to the fork-cms developers it seems like the imageprocessing ist done by the js-uploader of their MediaLibrary so does have nothing to do with ckfinder - I guess case closed then.